# Sub-linear-time ordered set (!= sorted set) implementation?

Tags: data-structures

Does there exist any data structure that efficiently (linearithmic-or-similar in-order traversal, sublinear time insertion/search/removal) implements an ordered set (i.e. a set that allows for enumerating the items in insertion order)?

If so, what data structure is it/how does it do this?

Comment: Doesn't a simple linked list meet your criteria (except for sublinear traversal, which doesn't make sense)?

Comment: @svick: My bad, typo about the traversal. But how exactly does a linked list do sublinear removal?

Comment: It's easy if you don't insist on linear-time traversal: use a set as normal, and associate some metadata with each entry to encode insertion order. Insert, remove, and search work just like for a set; when you want to iterate, just do a straight sort on the metadata first. Do you need linear traversal?

Comment: What _precisely_ does "search" mean in this context?  Find the rank of a given item?  Find the item with a given rank? Decide whether a given item is in the set at all? Or something else?

Comment: Another nice thing about such a structure as I describe above is that it can support, with no additional overhead, sorting based on the elements' natural ordering. Also, you might be able to use an auxiliary DS - a BST would work nicely - to start sorting as you're inserting elements; you'd go from const-time add/remove to log time, and you'd double the storage, but that would support everything, including linear traversal.

Comment: @JeffE: Existence.

Comment: @Patrick87: I **need** efficient traversal (read: linearithmic or similar). That's the whole point of my question. If I could have solved it with a linked list then there wouldn't have been any question to ask.

Comment: And do you only need efficient traversal of the complete set, or do you also need efficient traversal of smaller intervals?  (For example: "List the first k elements inserted after x", or "List all elements older than x but younger than y".)

Comment: @JeffE: Ah, great question -- only for the complete set, but in insertion order. I'm thinking a combination of a heap + BST might be helpful, but I'm not sure how to combine them to get it to do this.

Comment: If you need linear traversal, you should say so in the question text. Also, any thoughts on my second comment? That gives you everything you ask for, but requires more storage.

Comment: @Patrick87: I just did an edit, thanks for the suggestion. I don't need *linear* traversal per se, just something that's reasonably fast (probably n^1.5 or better should be fine, though I'm hoping for linearithmic). Regarding your second comment: it's interesting, lemme think about it a bit more.

Comment: I just learned a new word: "linearithmic".

Comment: @Raphael I had to look it up. For future reference, linarithmic is a portmanteau of "linear" and "logarithimc", and is to $O(n \log n)$ running time as linear is to $O(n)$ running time

Comment: @Joe: lol now I need to look up what "portmanteau" means.  :P

Answer (score 4):

Another pretty simple solution is a balanced binary search tree with threading (an overlaid linked list passing through all the nodes of the tree in order of their original insertion). Then insertion/search/removal are all O(log n), and iteration is O(n). You just update insert/remove to either append to the linked list or remove the node from it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I guess this is just a case of me being silly... thanks to the people who commented above who made me realize this.

I can just use a hashtable, and keep a counter along with the item.

To traverse in order of insertion? Just dump it into an array and sort it with respect to the counter.
Traversal is O(n) anyway, so O(n log n) sorting won't really make a difference.